# HP-LaserJet-P1006 does not print and shows completed

Tags: printer

I open Printers in Settings. I click Print Test Page. The tasks are updated. The task is marked as completed as seen in http://localhost:631/printers/HP-LaserJet-P1006?which_jobs=all
Nothing is printed.

How do I check the driver?
How to make sure the driver is correct?

The printer is installing on its own but I don't know if it gets the right driver. The problem started with first printing on elementary os when I printed pages 15-17 from pdf and the printer printed only 1 page, returned 2nd page as white and stopped because the paper was gone. I didn't receive any message to refill the paper, but I did so. The printer didn't continue to print next pages.

How to Reactivate HP LaserJet 1018/1020 after reloading paper?

Comment: Have you tried restarting both devices since this has happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have tried a lot different stuff.
I uninstalled Hplip and Reactive HP LaserJet 1018/1020 after reloading paper. (strange packet name, huh?)
It worked by default adding printer via Settings / Printers.